# weblogic.rjvm.PeerGoneException

Tags: weblogic-10.x

I'm using Weblogic 10.3.6. The bridges go into inactive state and when I check logs, I find the below error. Any idea to resolve this please?

```
<Dec 4, 2019 11:59:34 PM GMT> <Warning> <MessagingBridge> <BEA-200026> <Bridge "ABC_DEF_GHI" encountered some problems in one of its adapters or underlying systems. It stopped transferring messages and will try to reconnect to the adapters shortly. (The exception caught was weblogic.jms.common.LostServerException: java.lang.Exception: weblogic.rjvm.PeerGoneException: ; nested exception is:
        java.io.EOFException.)>
<Dec 4, 2019 11:59:34 PM GMT> <Warning> <MessagingBridge> <BEA-200026> <Bridge "ABC_DEF_GHI" encountered some problems in one of its adapters or underlying systems. It stopped transferring messages and will try to reconnect to the adapters shortly. (The exception caught was weblogic.jms.common.LostServerException: java.lang.Exception: weblogic.rjvm.PeerGoneException: ; nested exception is:
        java.io.EOFException.)>
<Dec 4, 2019 11:59:37 PM GMT> <Warning> <Connector> <
```

Answer (score 1):

As [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html) indicates, a `java.io.EOFException`:

> Signals that an end of file or end of stream has been reached unexpectedly during input.
>
> This exception is mainly used by data input streams to signal end of stream. Note that many other input operations return a special value on end of stream rather than throwing an exception.

Therefore I would conclude that the network connection used by the bridge has failed for some reason. I recommend you inspect the remote destination of the bridge as well as the network between them for any issues.